# Adding Google Font styles to DOM from Google Font API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, mime, draftjs

I am creating a text editor using Draftjs and would like to have a drop-down font selection menu. I have successfully got the data using a `axios` request and have used the `componentDidMount` react lifecycle method to add the data to my component state. I have mapped the font names to `<li>` tags in the drop-down menu.

So far so good, I have the data. What I want to happen is that when a font option is clicked from the drop-down menu, that font gets applied to the text (at the moment it's not important that selected text is changed, I just want to it work even if the whole doc is affected). I tried to add a `link` tag to the DOM with the url from the data but it is in the wrong format:

```
const link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
link.href = font.files.regular;
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

The font.files.regular property contains a url linked to the Google Font API but it's MIME type is `font/ttf` and I need `text/css`. I read that to use the `font/ttf` I have to make a CSS class with the `@font-face` property but I am unsure how to do that and then add it to the DOM element with the text.

Also the above code doesn't feel very 'Reacty', I tried using `React.createElement()` but when I tried 
`appendChild()` it threw an error saying that the element I'd created wasn't a DOM element. Some advice about how to get this working would be really appreciated.

p.s I am trying not to upload too much code as this is part of my final uni project and I've been warned about making code public as it could count as plagiarism (even though it's my code...). I'm not looking for a perfectly coded answer, just a nod in the right direction

Comment: You can preload the fonts with [`webfontloader`](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) and set classes for the different fonts. Then the dropdown can be used to change classes.

Comment: That looks really interesting thanks

Comment: You may also need to tinker with CSS specificity if the `Draft.js` library has its custom styles